# How two elements data-target one element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one html page `services.html`.

```
 <div id="serviceData">
       <div class="container table-options-section ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <select class="selectpicker col-sm-2">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                    </select>
             <input class="col-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Value">              
                <select id="productSelector" class="selectpicker col-sm-2">
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Go</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2"></th>
            <th rowspan="2"></th>
            <th rowspan="2"></th> 
            <th class="group-header net"></th>
            <th colspan="3" class="group-header buy"></th>
            <th colspan="3" class="group-header sell"></th>          
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data track by $index" class="noFocus">
            <td>{{}}</td>
            <td>{{}}</td>
            <td>{{}}</td>
            <td>{{}}</td>
            <td>{{}}</td>
            <td>{{}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to link it with two things.
One from my menu with name Service. When I click on it I want to open above HTML page (service.html).

`<li data-toggle="tab" data-target="#serviceData"><a>Service</a></li>`

Other from my navigation tab same name service. When I click on it same html page open.

`<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#serviceData">Service</a></li>`

Same id (serviceData)can not do it. 
So How to do it? Any Suggestions are Welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: include codes please

Comment: What do you mean by 'data-target it' ?

Comment: is `serviceData` a tab or modal ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean 1 link targets 2 different elements, or 2 different links target 1 element?

Answer (score 0):

Change your menu `li` code from:

`<li data-toggle="tab" data-target="#serviceData"><a>Service</a></li>`

to the following:

`<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#serviceData">Service</a></li>`